# How to create text file of dates when files in a directory were last edited

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a text file consisting of dates when all `.pzfx` files in a given directory were last edited. The big issue is that all the file names are not strings which complicates looping over them in a bash script.

Here is the bash script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f|grep .pzfx$ | while read file; do for i in "$file" stat -c ‘%y’ "$file" >> exp.dates.txt; done
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
./date.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `>>'
./date.sh: line 3: `find . -type f|grep .pzfx$ | while read file; do for i in "$file" stat -c ‘%y’ "$file" >> exp.dates.txt; done'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code just a bit to tweak your `find` and make things a bit easier to follow and was able to get it working.

Refactored Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_ext="${1:-.pzfx}"

while read -r ff ; do
    echo "${ff}"
    stat -c '%y' "${ff}" >> exp_dates.txt
done < <(find . -name "*${file_ext}" -type f)
```

Answer (score 4):

When redirecting the output of a loop, the `>>` has to be written after the `done`. Also, your inner `for` loop isn't necessary and is missing a `do` and `done`.

By the way: You don't need a loop at all when using `-exec`, which is also safer for filenames with whitespace.

```
find -type f -name \*.pzfx -exec stat -c %y {} + > exp.dates.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If using GNU `find` (and possibly others; check your local man page), you don't need `stat` at all:

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.pzfx" -printf "%t\n" > exp.dates.txt
```

The `%t` format is

> File's last modification time in the format returned by the C ctime(3) function.

For more flexible time formatting, use `%Tfmt`; see the manpage for a description of `fmt`.